# How to pass data to another storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

In an iPhone application, how do I pass data from one view (xib file) to another storyboard?

for example,

I have "welcome.xib" which contains nameTextfield and nextButton ,user will type their name into nameTextfield and click next

the app will navigate to "main.storyboard" and display the text from nameTextfield.text on userNameLabel in "main.storyboard"

what I know so far:

- I know how to pass data between views (from one xib file to another xib file)
- I know how to navigate from view(xib file) to another storyboard

Comment: "I know how to pass data between views (from one xib file to another xib file) "... so what's your question? Seems you already know the answer.

Comment: If you are using storyboards, why are you creating a separate xib for your welcome view controller instead of including it as part of your main.storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Override the -prepareForSegue:sender: method in your ViewController you want to pass the information from.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *sc = [segue destinationViewController];
    // Here you can set variables in detailViewController. For example if you had a NSString called name
    sc.name = @"name_here";
    // Or you could do
    [sc setName:@"name_here"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2+**

Add this to the view controller from wherein you want to send the data -

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard
            let destination = segue.destination as? viewControllerName
            else {
                return
        }
        destination.variable =data
    }
```

Make sure the name of the variable is the same as the one in where you want to send the data to, also the **viewControllerName** should be exactly similar.

Then use the following to perform the action either on a button click or inside any completionHandler -

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifierName", sender: nil)
```

**It is important to also make sure that the storyboard connecting the two should have the same identifier name as what you type inside the withIdentifier or the app will crash.**